# Serving files in heroku node js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, socket.io

I am new to node. I have created and successfully tested the node app in Heroku. My folder structure is something like this .

```
app.js ( the server side socket.iofile).
```

```
index.html (publicly available file).
```

when i access the app through the URL from

```
Heroku
```

.
If i access the

```
app.js
```

file like

```
appname.herokuapp.com/app.js
```

i can access the file. Is any way to prevent accessing this server file ?

Regards
Harilal

Comment: This is far too few information about your actual case: How is your http server build like (express/http?), how is middleware for static files loaded, what is your real directory structure...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, probably you are using express.static() due to which it can access any static file from your directory.Anyways, you can create a route for app.js:

```
var app=express();
app.use(app.router);            //this will make sure that node.js will check for a route  before checking for app.js file and displaying it.
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/directoryPath'));


//now set the route for app.js 

app.get('/app.js',function(req,res){

 //what-ever you want should happen when u go to appname.herokuapp.com/app.js
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually am not using the "express".
My code is something like this
http://pastebin.com/7BcZZsMk

My folder structure is like the following:

```
app
----css
--------style.css
----images
--------cup.png
--------tree.png
----app.js
----index.html
```